# How to auto quote a category name from a category post url in a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

Please there is something bothering me which I want to know.

I want to know how to quote a category name on any page using its category url of that post.

For example, if a post url is "arinzeifeanyi.gan.ng/jamb/new-jamb-policy and I want to automatically have a post under it as

Click Here to Read More **JAMB** News 
How will I do it. Please somebody help!

Answer (score 0):

To display the category name in single post page, use [the_category()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_category) function.

Click Here to Read More `<?php the_category(); ?>` News

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I appreciate.

Comment: I have read everything including the LOOP but still have not achieved it. Please can you throw more light on this